# Serializer 32 to 8 - Verilog HDL

Tags: verilog

I am trying to make serializer from 32bits to 8 bits. Because I am just starting verilog I am facing problem. I would like to get 32 bits (on every 4th clock cycles) and then to send 8 bits on every clock cycle. How can I take just part of my dataIn, I wrote code below but assignment expression is not working. Sorry if question is basic. Thank you in advance on answer.

```
module ser32to8(clk, dataIn, dataOut);
  input clk;
  input [32:0] dataIn;
  output [7:0] dataOut;

  always @(posedge clk) 
  begin
    dataOut <= dataIn << 8;
    end
    endmodule
```

Comment: 32 bits per 4 clock cycles, can you explain on this more?

Comment: @Emman I will load 32 bits, then I will need to wait 4 cycles till load them again. In mean time at output I will send 4x8 bits.

Comment: I could put counter, but I will get 32 bits on every 4th clock cycle. Module that is feeding data to ser32to8 is clocked by clk/4. So maybe I do not need counter. I would like just to shift bit by 8 spaces and to get them at the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you just take part of your dataIn data? By using the [] notation. dataIn[7:0] takes the 8 least significant bits, dataIn[15:8] takes the next 8 bits, and so on up to dataIn[31:24] which would take the 8 most significant bits.

To apply this to your problem, you can do like this (take into account that this is not an optimal solution, as outputs are not registered and hence, glitches may occur)

```
module ser32to8(
    input wire clk,
    input wire [31:0] dataIn,
    output reg [7:0] dataOut
    );

    reg [1:0] cnt = 2'b00;
    always @(posedge clk)
      cnt <= cnt + 1;

    always @* begin
      case (cnt)
        2'd0: dataOut = dataIn[7:0];
        2'd1: dataOut = dataIn[15:8];
        2'd2: dataOut = dataIn[23:16];
        2'd3: dataOut = dataIn[31:24];
        default: dataOut = 8'h00;
      endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: If `dataIn` is changed when `cnt > 0` , output is invalid. I think sampling from `dataIn` is necessary and must be applied when `cnt = 0`.

Comment: Yes... I warned about this being a suboptimal solution. This code was provided as an example on how to use the subindex operator to get only part of a variable, as that was his initial question: "how can I take just part of my dataIn?"

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the assignment failed (besides your code not doing any serialization) is because you didn't declare `dataOut` as a `reg`, and so you cannot assign to it inside an `always` block.

Here's how you do it correctly. (Since you didn't say in which order you wanted to serialize, I chose to go for lowest byte first, highest byte last. To reverse the order, exchange `>>` by `<<` and `tmp[7:0]` by `tmp[31:24]`.)

```
module ser32to8(
    input clk,
    input [31:0] dataIn,
    output [7:0] dataOut
);

// count: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, ... (wraps automatically)
reg [1:0] count;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    count <= count + 2'd1;
end

reg [31:0] tmp;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (count == 2'd0)
        tmp <= dataIn;
    else
        tmp <= (tmp >> 8);
end

assign dataOut = tmp[7:0];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the question is not so clear but my guess would be that you want to wait for 4 clock cycles before you send the data, if that is the case below snippet could help, A counter to wait before 4 clock cycles will do the trick

```
module top (input         clk,rst,
            input  [31:0] dataIn,
            output [7:0]  dataOut
            ); 
reg    [31:0] tmp; 
reg    [31:0] inter; 
integer       count;

always @(posedge clk) 
begin 
  if (rst) begin
    count <= 0;
    tmp   <= '0;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (count < 3) begin
      tmp <= dataIn << 4;
      count <= count +1; end
    else if (count == 3) 
      begin
      inter <= tmp;
      count <= 0;
      end
    else
      begin
        tmp <= dataIn;
      end
    end
end

assign dataOut  = inter[7:0]; 
endmodule
```

But there are some limitations tested with tb http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4Cg

> Note: Please ignore the previous code it won't work(I was not clear so
>   tried it differently)

**EDIT:**

If I understand your question correctly a simple way to do it is

a)

```
module top ( input         rst,clk,
             input  [31:0] dataIn,
             output [7:0]  dataOut);
reg [1:0] cnt;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) cnt <= 'b0;
  else     cnt <= cnt + 1;
end

assign dataOut = (cnt == 0) ? dataIn [7:0]   :
                 (cnt == 1) ? dataIn [15:8]  :
                 (cnt == 2) ? dataIn [23:16] :
                 (cnt == 3) ? dataIn [31:24] :
                  '0;

endmodule
```

Incase if you don't want to write it seperately for loop will come in handy to make it more simple

b)

```
module top ( input             rst,clk,
             input      [31:0] dataIn,
             output reg [7:0]  dataOut);
reg [1:0] cnt;
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) cnt <= 'b0;
  else     cnt <= cnt + 1;
end

always @ * begin
  for ( i =0;i < cnt ; i=i+1) begin 
    dataOut <= dataIn[(i*8)+:8]; end
end

endmodule
```

I have tried both with test cases and found to be working, tc's present @

a) http://www.edaplayground.com/x/VCF
b) http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4Cg

You may want to give it a try

Comment: I will test it. I do not want to wait 4 clock cycles to send data. I will get 32 bits on every 4th clk, and I want to send 8 bits on every clk.

Comment: `tmp <= dataIn` will never be executed, as `count` will only ever be either less than 3 or equal to 3. Not sure what it's supposed to do anyway.

Comment: And the module doesn't serialize anything, as you can see in the test bench you linked.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare `dataOut` as a reg, since you are using it in always block.Also, you are trying to assign 32 bit `datain` to 8 bit `dataout` , it is not logically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the figure below to design your circuit. Hope it can be useful with you. If you need the code, feel free to contact me.

[SER 112 bits with 8 outputs in parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FWeR.png)